# node.js node-cassandra-client request failing

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql

I keep running into the same issue when I'm trying to query a Cassandra Server. I have npm installed node-cassandra-client version 0.9.5.

```javascript
var Connection = require('cassandra-client').PooledConnection;

var hosts = ['host1:9160','host2:9160'];
var cassandra = new Connection({'hosts': hosts, 'keyspace': 'keyspace'});
cassandra.on('log', function(level, message, obj) {
  console.log('log event: %s -- %j', level, message);
});
var cql = "SELECT * FROM columnFamily LIMIT 1";

cassandra.execute(cql, function(err, rows) {
  if(err) console.log("erreur à la requete");

  console.log(rows);
  cassandra.shutdown(function() {
    console.log("connectoin pool shutdown");
  });
})
```

It seems the connection succeed. But I keep running into the following error :

```text
log event: info -- "connecting host:9160(1)"
log event: cql -- "SELECT * FROM columnFamily LIMIT 1"
DEBUG: 
DEBUG: /PATH/cassandra-client/node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/connection.js:90
DEBUG:         throw e;
DEBUG:               
DEBUG: ^
DEBUG: TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at /PATH/node_modules/cassandra-client/lib/driver.js:701:5
  at /PATH/node_modules/cassandra-client/lib/driver.js:716:15
  at /PATH/node_modules/cassandra-client/lib/driver.js:453:9
  at/PATH/node_modules/cassandra-      client/node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/connection.js:80:11
  at Object.recv_execute_cql_query (/PATH/node_modules/cassandra-client/lib/gen-nodejs/Cassandra.js:6219:12)
  at /PATH/node_modules/cassandra-cli ent/node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/connection.js:83:37
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/PATH/node_modules/cassandra-client/node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/transport.js:69:9)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:347:14)
DEBUG: Program node app.js exited with code 1
```

Whatever the request is, I keep having the same error.

Comment: I tried with Helenus instead of cassandra-client, and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but you're calling `cassandra.execute` with two parameters (query and callback) while it accepts three (query, list of query parameters and callback).

Try changing:

```
 cassandra.execute(cql, function(err, rows) {
     if(err) console.log("erreur à la requete");

     console.log(rows);
     cassandra.shutdown(function() {
         console.log("connectoin pool shutdown");
     });
 })
```

to

```
 cassandra.execute(cql, [], function(err, rows) {
     if(err) console.log("erreur à la requete");

     console.log(rows);
     cassandra.shutdown(function() {
         console.log("connectoin pool shutdown");
     });
 })
```

Comment: that is not necessary. parameter is optional

Comment: @Abhi it used to be mandatory in version 0.9.5, since `execute` called `bind` directly, which in turn used `.length` of the second argument. [Check for yourelf](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client/blob/v0.9.5/lib/driver.js#L410-L411)